What causes broken Git references?
Just helped a friend debug a "broken git reference." Fixing was easy enough update-ref -d or rm -r .git/refs/..., but I still don't understand what causes this in the first place.
I have a medium-high understanding of git under the hood, but I've not dug too deep into the actual .git directory.
How are branches/refs stored in .git and what about that causes broken references? He hadn't done anything unusual when this happened.

Git references are just pointers to SHA-1 hashes of commits that can  point to branches, tags, etc.
They are  stored in files, like almost anything in Git, so some of possible breaking reasons are:

unexpected system shutdown when something wrote to the file
faulty disk, file system, etc.
git process interrupted at incorrect time

or anything alike that can cause generic problems with files.
Another possible reason is that someone force pushed and the remote failed to update properly, so the local git instance got confused after pulling. Or any similar sort of desync.

Thanks! Wonder what it was this time...
